# Data in several rows into one row and columns

Tags: r

I have a table, where data is stored in a following pattern:

```
ID Account
1  A
1  B
2  B
3  A
4  A
4  B
```

I would like to get one row per ID in a following way:

```
ID Account_A Account_B
1  1         1
2  0         1
3  1         0
4  1         1
```

0s and 1s don't matter that much, can be As, Bs etc. The main problem is to get data into one row per ID so I can merge it with another table.

I am not too familiar with **R**, so simpler solutions without too many new libraries are preferred.

Comment: What do you mean by table?  `data.table` or maybe `data.frame` or `matrix`?

Comment: @dvantwisk My bet is "CSV since I haven't opened up R yet."

Comment: `library(data.table); dcast(TABLE, ID ~ paste0("Account_", Account))`

Comment: `library(reshape2)`; `dcast(dt, ID~Account)` should do it

Comment: @PoG and Sagar: Fyi, OP requested base R in the last sentence.

Comment: It´s a data frame, by not being familiar I meant that e.g. I haven´t used data.table at all yet. The codes you submitted don´t look as complicated as data.table solutions I have seen for other problems, so I will try them.

Comment: Using reshape2 solution I got a message "Using Account as value column: use value.var to override.", but I used the reshape function solution and got no errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a solution with the base R function `reshape`.

The data:

```
dat <- data.frame(ID = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 4, 4), Account = c("A", "B", "B", "A", "A", "B"))
```

Transform the data to the wide format with `reshape`.

```
dat_wide <- reshape(dat, direction = "wide", v.names = "Account", idvar = "ID",
                    timevar = "Account", sep = "_")

dat_wide
#     ID Account_A Account_B
#   1  1         A         B
#   3  2      <NA>         B
#   4  3         A      <NA>
#   5  4         A         B
```

The values can be replaced with `1` and `0`:

```
dat_wide[-1] <- as.integer(!is.na(dat_wide[-1]))
#   ID Account_A Account_B
# 1  1         1         1
# 3  2         0         1
# 4  3         1         0
# 5  4         1         1
```

Comment: One more question - is it possible to combine this code with counting number of occurences? In another data frame I have a similar layout, but for given example Account "A" can occur multiple times for same ID, then I would like to get a similar summary, but with a result similar to using COUNT() function in Excel.

Answer (score 1):

We need `table()`, then prettify to match the expected output.

**Note:** I am using new example data to match OP's request regarding duplicated rows.

> [PrzeM commented:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46200806/r-data-in-several-rows-into-one-row-and-columns#comment79366397_46201303)
>   One more question - is it possible to combine this code with counting
>   number of occurences? In another data frame I have a similar layout,
>   but for given example Account "A" can occur multiple times for same
>   ID, then I would like to get a similar summary, but with a result
>   similar to using COUNT() function in Excel.

```
# based on OP comments new example data
df1 <- read.table(text = "ID Account
1  A
1  A
9  B
9  B
3  A
4  A
4  B", header = TRUE)

# get table and convert to a dataframe
myTable <- table(df1)
res <- as.data.frame.matrix(myTable)
res
#   A B
# 1 2 0
# 3 1 0
# 4 1 1
# 9 0 2

# update column names for Accounts
colnames(res) <- paste("Account", colnames(res), sep = "_")

# ID is in rownames, add it back as new column
res$ID <- rownames(res)

# reorder columns to get desired output
res <- res[, c(3, 1, 2)]
rownames(res) <- NULL
res
#   ID Account_A Account_B
# 1  1         2         0
# 2  3         1         0
# 3  4         1         1
# 4  9         0         2
```